# What is the big oh for comparing two binary trees?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, big-o

If one binary tree has x nodes and the other has y nodes where x is bigger than y. I was thinking O(n<sup>2</sup>) because searching for each node is O(n).

*And how about inserting then comparing the trees?*

Comment: Are they binary search trees (i.e. the nodes are in some kind of sorted order), or are they "just trees"? If they're "just trees", then it's an O(x*y) problem unless you use some extra memory for a hash table. If they are binary search trees, then it's an O(x+y) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your binary trees are *sorted,* this is an O(n) operation (where `n` is the sum of the nodes in both trees, *not* the product).

You can simply run two "indexes" side by side through the trees stopping when an element is different. If you get to the end of *both* and no differences were found, then the trees were identical, something like the following pseudo-code:

```
def areEqual (tree1, tree2):
    pos1 = first (tree1)
    pos2 = first (tree2)
    while pos1 != END and pos2 != END:
        if tree1[pos1] != tree2[pos2]:
            return false
        pos1 = next (tree1, pos1)
        pos2 = next (tree2, pos2)
    if pos1 != END or pos2 != END:
        return false
    return true
```

If they're *not* sorted, and you have no other information that may allow you to optimise the function, and cannot use extra data structures, it will be O(n<sup>2</sup>), since you'll have to find an arbitrary equal node in the second tree for every single node in the first (as well as mark it somehow to indicate you've used it).

---

Keep in mind there are usually ways to trade space for time if the former is more important (and it often is).

For example, even with totally unordered trees, you can reduce the complexity considerably by using hashing for example:

```
def areEqual (tree1, tree2):
    hash = []

    # Add all items from first tree.

    for item in tree1.allItems():
        if not exists hash[item]
            hash[item] = 0
        hash[item] += 1

    # Subtract all items from second tree.

    for item in tree2.allItems():
        if not exists hash[item]
            hash[item] = 0
        hash[item] -= 1
        if hash[item] == 0:
            delete hash[item]

    if hash.size != 0:
        return false

    return true
```

Since hashing tends to amortise toward O(1), the problem as a whole can be considered O(n).

Comment: if it was an inorder traversal of the first binary tree and every value u find u have to search it in the other binary tree...is that n^2?

Comment: @user180505, that depends, there are ways to make it better, I've updated the answer with some more detail.

Comment: If the trees are not sorted, shouldn't the comparison then be O(N log n) since you won't need to search more than one tree while iterating the other?

Comment: @Lasse, iterating the first tree would be N operations. For each of those, searching the other tree would be N operations (would be logN if it was sorted but it isn't). Hence n^2 overall. I think O(NlogN) would be the case if one tree was sorted and the other wasn't.